# How to install Java 12

Tags: raspbian, java

I am trying to install java 12 on my pi. I can only use the terminal. 
Any Ideas what I have to do? it seems that java 12 isnt in the Repositorys.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why specifically version 12? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using Ubuntu try this:**

```
sudo apt install openjdk-12-jdk
```

Use the following command to verify the installed version of Java on your system.

```
java -version
```

**If you are using Debian try this:**

Create a new Apt configuration file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-13-debian.list, and edit in text editor.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-13-debian.list
```

and add following content in it.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main
```

Now import GPG key on your system for validating packages before installing them.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EA8CACC073C3DB2A
```

Run the following commands to update apt-cache and then install Java 13 on the Debian system using the apt-get package manager.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java13-installer
```

Use the following command to verify the installed version of Java on your system.

```
java -version
java version "13" 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: But on Debian/Raspbian (that's what the OP use) it will install version 13 and not version 12 as asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the BellSoft Liberica JDK's on Raspbian.

If you start from a fresh Raspbian you will have version 11

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-post-Raspbian-5)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-post-Raspbian-5, mixed mode)
```

Easiest way to install:

- Visit https://bell-sw.com/
- Look for the version you want to use for "Linux ARM v7 & v8 32 bit HardFloat"
- Copy the link location to the deb-file
- Run the following script (is for the version 12.0.2 you are looking for)
- Check if the version installed correctly by running "java -version" again

$ cd /home/pi

$ wget https://download.bell-sw.com/java/12.0.2/bellsoft-jdk12.0.2-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb

$ sudo apt-get install ./bellsoft-jdk12.0.2-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb

$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: You downloaded `bellsoft-jdk12.0.2-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb` (**jdk12**) and installed `bellsoft-jdk13-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb` (**jdk13**)? Really?

Comment: Sorry @Ingo my mistake, copy/paste and only half adapted ;-) Fixed now!